django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'path': ['Page with this Path already exists.']}
I am getting a django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'path': ['Page with this Path already exists.']} when attempting to create a new page.
I have the following page tree:
$ from wagtail.models import Page

$ [(p.url, p.path) for p in Page.objects.all()]

[(None, '0001'),
 ('/en-us/', '00010001'),
 ('/en-us/events/', '000100010001'),
 ('/en-us/events/webinars/', '0001000100010001'),
 ('/en-us/events/webinars/some-webinar/', '00010001000100010001'),
 ('/en-us/events/newsletter/', '0001000100010002')]

When I try to add a new page (from wagtail's admin) under events, I get a django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'path': ['Page with this Path already exists.']}. From the interactive debugger I can see that the attempted new page's path is set to '0001000100010002'.
I have tried running python manage.py fixtree as suggested in related issues with no success, i.e., I get:
Checking page tree for problems...
No problems found.

Checking collection tree for problems...
No problems found.

How can this be solved? I am using django 4.2.9 and wagtail 5.2.3 (with wagtail-localize 1.8, wagtailmenus 3.1.9 and wagtail-metadata 4.0.2).

Try:
python manage.py fixtree --full


The command output is:
Checking page tree for problems...
All problems fixed.

Checking collection tree for problems...
All problems fixed.

yet nothing changes, I encounter the same error and the page paths remain the same.

Did you use --full? That flag is needed to actually rearrange a tree if it is broken. Other things to try: check your version of django-treebeard and if --full doesn't fix it, you can get a python shell and run treebeard's find_problems to try to get more information https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard/blob/fe35cd2d33bed11946f8c28ee34aa2aaca2de73d/treebeard/mp_tree.py#L669

I did use the --full flag. treebeard's version is 4.7.1. I ran find_problems for each page and always got ([], [], [], [], []) as result.

Sorry I think you are going to need to set a breakpoint and figure out what path the new page is trying to use and then figure out why it clashes.

I have used the interactive debugger and I may have a clue:
mp tree gets "webinars" as the last child (here: https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard/blob/4.7.1/treebeard/mp_tree.py#L383), i.e.:
self.node.get_last_child()
<Page: Webinars>



self.node.get_last_child().path
'0001000100010001'



but the last child would actually be "newsletter", i.e.:



for page in self.node.get_children(): print(page, page.path)
Newsletter 0001000100010002
Webinars 0001000100010001



I suppose this is an issue of wagtail/treebeard, should I file it in their github?
